# mpdf @page css not working in all browsers for print page size

Tags: php, css, printing, mpdf

I am using below css for printing with this sizes (A4, A5) with landscape and portrait orientation in pdf file using mpdf but its not working at all in all browsers. Please provide me any solution or provide me another example for this problem.

```
$html="
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        @page {
            size: 8.5in 11in landscape;
            margin: 10px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Print this heading for all printing page with landscape and portrait orientation.</h2>
</body>
</html>";

$mpdf = new mPDF(); 
$mpdf->AddPage();
$mpdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->AliasNbPages();
$mpdf->Output();
```

Comment: did you tried using : @media print
   {
      your css here
   }

Comment: Yes i have tried this but it did'nt work.